# How to reduce time for cloning in vm?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

1 . I have 10 hosts and i need to add 5 guest os to each host machine . Am cloning from one vm to another. It is taking almost 40 to 50 mins to complete is there any solution to reduce time to vms ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several actually. It all depends on the environment.
Are you using vCenter
Do you have centralized storage
Is the storage network separate from your mgmt and vm traffic network
If so what is the connection speed between the SAN and the Hosts

This isnt much an answer more or less a recommendation. If youre not using vcenter and you dont have centralized storage then there isnt much you can do.

Comment: am using vcenter